# How do I use AJAX to GET info from server without resetting the session timeout?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, session, timeout

I would like to make a periodic background request from JavaScript on the client to my web application (ASP.NET, IIS 7), but I don't want the request to affect the ASP.NET session timeout.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to avoid sending cookies with your request because that's how session ids are transmitted.

If you have an xmlHTTPRequest object, you can remove your cookie header by calling `xmlHTTPRequest.setRequestHeader("Cookie", "");`