# Session time out not working properly

Tags: java, ajax, session-timeout

In my web application I have set the session timeout for 30 minutes. But users has complained me that the application session doesn't time out properly. In clint side once a 30 seconds it sends ajax requst to the webserver to retrieve data from the server. Is this automated ajax request avoid the session being time out. Can some one pls explain.

Comment: This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834270/how-do-i-execute-an-authenticated-ajax-request-without-resetting-the-tomcats-ses

Comment: What are users complaining? That it times out too early, or that it doesn't time out at all?

Comment: Actually it doesn't time out at all..

Comment: Well as Peter has said, the reason for that is because your page is making an ajax request every 30 seconds. The session will only time out if the user navigates away from the page or closes their browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session timeout means that if a request is not made for certain time (30 min) then user session is deleted/invalidated.

Every AJAX request is of course treated as any other HTTP request and will reset the timeout.

So an app making AJAX requests every 30 seconds, will never reach a session timeout.