# On Session Timeout Login.gsp is rendered within the <body> tag instead of redirecting to a new gsp page

Tags: session, grails, authentication, timeout

I am new to Grails and working on a project which has just 2 controllers one is for login and the other is for a explorer (similar to a windows explorer with left panel displaying a tree -like structure and the right displays the folders contents as a table)

The application is working as excpected meaning when user accesses the application it displays Login Screen if user hasn't logged in  and if he has logged in it displays the explorer screen.

But this is not the case on session Timeout: suppose the session has timed out and the user clicks on a link in the right panel of the explorer screen then the login screen is displayed within the right panel.

I am using SecurityFilter to redirect to login screen.

SecurityFilters.groovy

def filters = {

```
    loginCheck(controller:'*', action:'*') {
        before = {
    if (!session.idpuser && actionName != "login") {
                redirect(controller: "user", action: "login")                   
                return false 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

userController.groovy

def login () {

```
if (request.get) {        
  return false
}
......  
 redirect(controller: "explorer", action: "file")
```

}

explorerController.groovy

def generateFiles = {

```
.....
render(template: 'list', model: [ dirList: dirList])
```

}

UrlMappings.groovy

static mappings = {

```
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/"(action:"file", controller: "explorer")  
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

The reason I think login.gsp is being rendered in the right panel is because when a user click on a link in right panel "generateFiles" action is invoked and that is rendering  login.gsp as a template within explorer.gsp. But I dont know how to fix it :(

I would appreciate if someone can help me with this issue. 
PLEASE HELP!!!!!

Comment: Is this an Ajax-y application, or is the whole page being reloaded for the user-action in question?

Comment: Yes for every click on the explorer page an Ajax call is made to retrieve the data

Comment: You should have a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834270/how-do-i-execute-an-authenticated-ajax-request-without-resetting-the-tomcats-se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is an ajax based site, you need to explicitly handle the "you need to login" response in your ajax response handlers and force the user to the login page if needed.

Comment: The response/data I get from a the Ajax call is the contents of Login.gsp and so I tried $(document).html(data) but it went into an infinite loop and my browser crashed. (I knew that wasn't the right way :( was looking for a quick fix).  Is there a way to redirect to a GSP page from javascript

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the solution may not be an efficient way but it works.Based on the response I get from the Ajax call I am redirecting to Login.gsp using

`window.location.href = '${createLink(controller='user', action='login')}'`

Thank you cdeszaq for the hint. I really appreciate it.