# opening modal from server side, grails

Tags: session, grails, modal-dialog

I am trying to show modal after session expired. I am using filters to catch that session has expired:

```
def filters = {
    all(controller:'graphs', action:'*') {
        before = {
            if (session.expired) {
                //some code to invoker modal
                return false
             }
        }           
    }
}
```

Modal should notify the user that session has expired and redirect to main page. Any suggestions on how to invoke modal?

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing is very tricky to implement because you need a client-initiated request or session to transmit *anything* to the client and any such request will prolong the session. I see two possibilities:

#### Polling

If you don't mind the session being prolonged and just want to make sure the user is still logged in the simplest way would be to implement Javascript polling using `setInterval` or similar (but make sure the polling stops on first failure or users are at risk getting redirected to the polling endpoint after logging in again, especially if they have more than one tab open). If you don't want to stretch the session you could try a [hacky workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834270/how-do-i-execute-an-authenticated-ajax-request-without-resetting-the-tomcats-se).

#### Websockets

You could open a websocket connection using an appropriate [plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-websocket) and keep it open. You need to make sure no session prolonging heartbeats are being sent. Then when the session ends, send a message back through the connection. Note that this will involve more work than polling.